# GeoGraphics high resolution hybrid satellite-map

Tags: geography, geographics

Is it possible to get a hybrid (map and satellite) high-resolution map similar to what we get from Google Earth Maps?

```
GeoGraphics[
 GeoMarker[
  Entity["City", {"London", "GreaterLondon", "UnitedKingdom"}]], 
 GeoRange -> Quantity[1, "Miles"], GeoZoomLevel -> Automatic, 
 GeoBackground -> "Satellite"]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: How about `ImageCompose`?

Comment: @SjoerdC.deVries, I tried this (https://www.wolfram.com/mathematica/new-in-10/geographic-visualization/overlay-a-street-map-with-a-contour-map.html) but not success. The Satellite map is too bad.

Comment: So your question is not about combining graphics, but about obtaining better satellite images? If so, you probably should state that more clearly in your question.

Comment: @SjoerdC.deVries it is actually both combining graphics and better satellite images. I did not say I succeeded in any of them.

Comment: Would using `GeoServer` help?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Using `GeoServer` in Mathematica 11 you can download a hybrid map from Google:

```
GeoGraphics[
 GeoMarker[
  Entity["City", {"London", "GreaterLondon", "UnitedKingdom"}]], 
 GeoRange -> Quantity[1, "Miles"], 
 GeoBackground -> GeoStyling["StreetMap"], 
 GeoServer -> "http://mt0.google.com/vt/lyrs=s,h&x=`2`&y=`3`&z=`1`"]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: That is great. Thanks

Comment: `DynamicGeoGraphics[...]` works too (Simply replace `GeoGraphics[...]` by `DynamicGeoGraphics[...]`)